# What is the procedure of buying a new car?

Tags: buying, license-plates

I am a new student in the US. I found a vehicle on the Facebook market place from a private owner and I want to buy it in cash. But I don't know how the things going in the US and what is the procedure of buying a new car in the US? Should I pay all the money to the seller at the first and will he give the car to me? Should he give me some other things like the car's license, ETC?  When should I go to DMV? How much is the prices at the DMV(California)? Should I pay those prices by myself too? If I live in the north of the CA and the car is in another city at the middle, where should I go to DMV? At the city the seller lives or at the city I do live?

It would be a pleasure if someone writes a complete guide for new car buyers(After choosing a car to buy) in the US(California).

Comment: Do you mean a *used* car? What's a DMV? Have you read [Buying a Car in California - What You Need to Know](https://www.autolist.com/guides/buying-car-california)?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure this question falls into "Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair" but generally the procedures are similar across states with some variations.

In California there is an official document call a TITLE that shows ownership and has a place for the seller to assign ownership to the buyer.  Generally when you purchase from a dealer, they are, for the most part, bound by state laws governing their conduct.  With a private seller, well, all bets are off.  BE CAREFUL!  (You should also be careful and check reviews and reference for dealers.)

Things to be careful of include:

1. Forged titles or titles in another person's name from the supposed seller.
2. The VIN number on the car being different from the vehicle being purchased.
3. SALVAGE or REBUILT title status.  This means the vehicle was "totaled" and someone did work to restore it to drivable status.  They may or may not have done good work.
4. Liens, the title may have a lien on it which means someone used it as collateral for a loan.  Be sure any liens are removed before you hand over any money.
5. Don't EVER send money to someone on a promise.  There are so many scams here that I don't have room to list them all but be aware that private selling of cars is a prime scam target.  Again, BE CAREFUL.  If ANYTHING is not up-and-up RUN AWAY!
6. Be very careful meeting for an exchange.  It's not unheard of to be robbed since you have money and they know it.  Meet at a police station or a bank or someplace where you will not be vulnerable.

There are a lot of other things to keep in mind and I'm sure some others will jump in and list them too.

Once you have the endorsed title you will take that to the DMV and apply for a new title in your name.  Plan to spend some money on that and I think CA also will collect sales tax on your purchase.  You'll also need to get a registration and license plates at the DMV.  That, of course, costs more money.  To get that you'll need proof of insurance and I believe a CA drivers license as well.

Comment: In CA, don't the plates go with the vehicle? I understood there it was cradle to grave with the plates? (I could be wrong ... as how do personalized plates work there?) Also, in order to get the stuff done at the DMV, I'm pretty sure you need to have some type of ID to prove who you are.

Comment: Regardless of the plates you still need the registration, which is what the $$$ goes for.

Comment: Oh, wasn't contradicting you at all. Was trying to add to what you're saying.

Comment: Generally I'd recommend that a new buyer buy from a well known and well respected local dealer.  The dealer will help you navigate through the maze of regulations that is today's California.  It may seem like it costs more but getting swindled is very expensive.